# How can I update a plot with periodic information coming through a serial port (every ~100-200 msec)? Do I need an RTOS?

Tags: python, plot, serial-port, embedded, microcontroller

I'm sending positioning information (x,y,z coordinates in double data type) from a microcontroller via a Serial Communication Interface (SCI). I would like to use a program to receive this information and update this coordinate every time I receive a new coordinate, preferably in Python.

What is a good library to do this? Do I need a Real Time Operating System (and why?)? Should I use a different communication interface (and why?)?

Comment: In addition to 100-200 msec being *on average* within the capability of a well-configured desktop OS, it sounds very much like the timing of the sampling in your setup is dictated by the remote embedded system.  As a result, lag on the desktop will likely only result in the data being plotted a little late, but no actual jitter in the timing of the measurement.  That usually ends up working out fine - the system functions with hard timing from the embedded end, even if  sometimes the human watching the screen is notified a fraction of a second late (or occasionally more).

Answer (score 2):

No, an RTOS is not necessary. Any modern system should very easily be able to handle reading serial data every 100ms.

Just get started reading from the serial port, and processing your data.

- [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: But the plotting is the part that I'm worried about. I know I can take in data using pySerial. But once I plot that data, how do I add data to that plot while still trying to read more data? The plotting features I've seen have an option called "hold on" but I can't hold on and receive more data.

Comment: You probably won't want to update the plot every time you get another sample. One design might include a background thread that gathers data from the serial port, and queues it up, while the GUI thread periodically pulls the most recent batch of data and updates the plot.

Comment: Ok. And thats what I'm really doing now. I have one script that gathers data and saves it into a file. Then another script plots the data in the file. I'm artificially delaying the system so that I can see every point (I'm trying to test the quality of my coordinates right now). But you're right. When I run the system at full speed, I probably don't need to display all the results. Is there an efficient GUI that I can use that isn't the Plot function?

Comment: @user2525288 There are innumerable libraries for drawing to a GUI. It all depends on the features, portability, flexibility, speed, easy of use etc. you're looking for. Usually you only get to pick a few of those characteristics. By `"the Plot function"` I'm assuming you're talking about matplotlib, which would not be very good for a "realtime" GUI.

Comment: @user2525288 writing data from one thread and reading it from another is just about the worst means of inter-thread comms ever considered.